# using typed hoc at untyped component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recompose

I'm gradually moving my current react project into typescript.
While doing that, I've met some strange situation.

```
// MyComponent.js
import {someHoc} from 'recompose' // is typed by DefinitelyTyped.

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
}

const component = someHoc(options)(MyComponent)
export default component
```

When I imported `MyComponent` from a typed code, typescript check the Props of `MyComponent` and throw errors on type checking `someHoc`

1. Why they check type from JS module? I think tsc should not check the type of exported `component`, cause it is written on JS
2. How can I suppress this error without converting `MyComponent` to typescript?

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that you are not exporting `MyComponent` but a HOC wrapped `component` here. Typescript is not checking the type of `MyComponent` but of the component returned by `someHoc(options)(MyComponent)`

Comment: Yeah, that's how to use hoc. So it could never be the problem i guess. But, does typescript checks returned class? not the code?